# Adding Environment variables to GCP Workflows using Pulumi

Tags: pulumi, google-workflows, pulumi-python

Using Python pulumi_gcp, I am deploying a Workflow and an Eventarc Trigger.

However, I do not see a way to add an environment variable to the Workflow as part of the Workflow function:

```
my_workflow = workflows.Workflow('my-workflow',
                    description="my workflow",
                    project=project.project_id,
                    region="us-east1",
                    source_contents=<get from GitHub>,
                    service_account=gcp_service_account,
                    opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(depends_on=[workflows_api])
)
```

I have researched the Pulumi Python API, examples and unfortunately the workflows resource does not support import.

Thanks!